# why doesn't "echo $?" print the exit code of the command right before it while used in "&&"?

Tags: bash, echo, exit-code

Suppose I have this simple C program that returns 4 to the shell.

```
int main()
{
  return 4;
}
```

When I run it, then do `echo $?`, I would get `4`, which is expected

```
$ gcc foo.c && ./a.out
$ echo $?
4               <<<< expected
```

BUT when I do the following, I'm  NOT getting anything

```
$ gcc foo.c && ./a.out && echo $?
$             <<<< Nothing - WHY????
```

Answer (score 5):

`&&` only runs the second argument if the first one was successful, i.e. if it finished with exit code 0. Exit code 4 means "failure" for the shell, so the `echo` is not executed. Try

```
gcc foo.c && ./a.out || echo $?
```

If you want to see the exit code only when it's not zero. If you want to see it always, use

```
gcc foo.c && ./a.out ; echo $?
```

Note that it can report the exit code of the `gcc` if it's not zero.